# Linux: prevent two default routes from being added

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, network-interface, routing

I have a "host" Raspberry Pi with wlan0 and some USB ports. I have another "client" Pi that I connect to the host Pi via USB cable (the client Pi has no other network interfaces that are active). The client Pi is running g_ether so that when it is connected to the host via USB cable, it establishes an Ethernet-over-USB connection (creating "eth1" on the host). Also, when the client device is connected, I know that the client device will be at 192.168.42.1 and the host Pi will get an address assigned by the client on that network (192.168.42.x). When the client is connected, it adds a second default route to the host Pi's routing table. So the routing table on the host Pi ends up with two default routes:

```
default via 192.168.42.1 dev eth1 proto dhcp src 192.168.42.21 metric 204
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.125 metric 303
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.125 metric 303
192.168.42.0/24 dev eth1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.42.21 metric 204
```

Since wlan0 is my usual route to the Internet, this second default route breaks my route to the Internet. And I'd like simultaneous routes to the Internet (via wlan0) and to 192.168.42.1 (via eth1). For example, with the client device not connected I can ping ntp.org (via wlan0). But with the client device connected I cannot ping ntp.org (presumably because it is trying to go through the newly-added second default route created by my client device, which has no route to the Internet).

I discovered that deleting the second default route fixes the problem (I can ping ntp.org and I can still ping 192.168.42.1).

How do I prevent this second default route from being added in the first place? Or is there another solution?

Answer (score 3):

Adding `nogateway` for `eth1` to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` fixed my problem:

```
interface eth1
nogateway
```

Props to the dhcpcd.conf man page (and a +1 to ChatGPT for pointing me in the general direction):
https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd.conf.5.en.html